# Incorrect results from DSP48: possibly using 1's complement instead of 2's

Tags: fpga, verilog, dsp, vivado

I'm using Vivado to write code for an Ultrascale+ FPGA in Verilog and I'm facing an issue with a DSP48. The DSP seems to be outputting the wrong result.

I have manually added a DSP through the IP catalog and the DSP is configured to compute P := A*B + C, where A, B and C are all wires and A is 27 bit long, B is 18 and C is 48. Now, when I simulate the block containing the DSP in Vivado 2020.1, I don't always get the result I expect from the DSP. In particular, I noticed that I get unexpected results whenever the most significant bit of B is 1 (in my current tests, the MSB of A is always 0). Moreover, the results I get appear similar to the negation of the expected product, so I'm assuming it might somewhat related to signed multiplication.

Thus, my questions are:

- Is that a correct assessment of the situation?
- If so, how do I make the DSP compute the unsigned product?

Here's a minimum example of my problem:

```vhdl
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module small_alu1 (clk, s0, s1, a0, a1, a0s0, a0s1_a1s0, a1s1);
input clk;
input [12:0] a0, a1;
input  [3:0] s0, s1;
output [12:0] a0s0, a0s1_a1s0, a1s1;

wire [26:0] A = {a1[10:0],  3'b0, a0};
wire [17:0] S = {s1[1:0], 13'b0, s0[2:0]};

wire [47:0] result;
wire [47:0] C = 47'b0;

dsp_1827 DSP(.clk(clk), .A(A), .B(S), .C(C), .P(result));

wire [12:0] a0s0 =      result[12:0];
wire [12:0] a0s1_a1s0 = result[28:16];
wire [12:0] a1s1 =      result[44:32];


endmodule
```

When A = 2_0001 (in hex) and S = 3_0004 (also in hex), after the delay due to pipelining, result is equal to fffe_0007_0004, rather than the expected 6_000B_0004.

The DSP is a DSP48 Macro (3.0), it has only one instruction set to A*B+C, which means there are three incoming ports (CLK, A{26:0], B[17:0], C[47:0}) and one outcoming (P[47:0]), pipelining is set to automatic and the implementation options list the port sizes as above, full precision output and no additional ports used, while Use DSP slice is set to on.

EDIT: after more research, I suspect that signs have nothing to do with this, but instead the DSP expects the input and outputs the result in 1's complement. Is that normal behaviour? And if so, is it possible to have it use two's complement?

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: If you have unambiguously signed or unsigned types in Verilog (like VHDL's numeric_std) use them consistently, and you should get exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @EugeneSh. added it, sorry for not including it from the start.

Comment: @BrianDrummond my understanding is that by default everything is unsigned in Verilog and there's no way to mark it as such, but I might be missing something.

Comment: How about the DSP block? How it's signals are defined?

Comment: Maybe System Verilog has better options?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've added the configurations of the DSP to te question. There's no other setting available in the configuration screen in Vivado

Comment: @BrianDrummond SystemVerilog is not an option due to other constraints. There should be a way to achieve this in Verilog, no?

Comment: I don't recall one when I looked at Verilog. But that was in the 1990s, and convinced me to stick to VHDL.

Comment: If this is Xilinx Specific, you'll have better luck asking on Xilinx's forums.

Answer (score -1):

Your input \$S\$ is 18 bits, so 0x3_0004 is a negative number (assuming that you really have a signed multiplier). \$0x3\,0004 = -0x0\,\text{FFFC} = -65532\$. Your 26-bit value for \$A\$ is positive, so you should expect a negative result. I think your multiplier is working.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Firstly, I see your point, but I'm not sure it works out. Can you show me how  2_0001 * 3_0004 = fffe_0007_0004, even with a signed multiplier? And secondly, I would ideally need an unsigned multiplier. Is it not possible to get a DSP to multiply without signs?

Comment: 0x3_0004 = -65532 and 0x002_0001 = 131073.   65532 * 131073 = 8589475836 = 0x0001_FFF8_FFFC.    -0x0001_FFF8_FFFC = 0xFFFE_0007_0004.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Xilinx DSP48 blocks; I don't know if they can be configured to perform unsigned multiplication.